# Random loss of static IP (multi-homed setup)

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp

I have few Raspberry PIs installed Ubuntu Mate 15.10 and configured them with both DHCP and static IP addresses on eth0.  The /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# multi IPs
allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.31/24
```

Also, I disable network manager to control the eth0.  `nmcli dev` shows all are unmanaged as suggested by some users:

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
eth0    ethernet  unmanaged  --
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
wlan0   wifi      unmanaged  --
```

It works perfectly from every boot up and `ip addr` returns eth0 info with both DHCP and static IP address:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state     UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:e0:40:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.142/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.33/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

192.168.1.142 is from DHCP server (router) and 192.168.0.33 is the static one.
I can access the units from both IPs perfectly. in fact, it is a multi-homed setup.

However, the static IP is lost randomly every few hours, leaving only DHCP IP.  Whenever it happens, `ip addr` will find static IP missing.  Seems that some events happened will remove the static one.  I need to run "sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0" to recover it every time.

I tried hard to search every forum about static IP setup and tried many different suggested modifications but I have no luck in solving the random loss static IP.

Current setup is like a setting a Windows notebook configured for home (DHCP) and work (static ip address).  I hope my Ubuntu can be accessed in any DHCP environment yet accessed via static known IPs.

Comment: You can set static IP addresses in network-manager for different networks similar to how you would in windows and I have never had an issue with having the IP change when set to static as network-manager has it set static for that particular network.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  However, I need headless configuration without using monitor and keyboard.  That's why I need setup like this.